# Making sharepoint Url Clickable

Tags: url, library, hyperlink, settings

I want the URL to be a hyperlink when In the SharePoint Library Settings page. It would be much nicer than copy paste all the time. Is there anyway to do this?[image: Part circled in red is what I would like a Hyperlink]

Comment: This page is a template page available in layout folder. I have done changing in some pages. But not in the list settings page.

Comment: Okay I will look. Any ideas as for the code for always making this link clickable?

Comment: There will be a string literal. Add that to an anchor tag with href property set to it. Simple HTML. :)

Comment: I would definitely suggest against changing anything in the layouts folder, writing an alternative solution now

Comment: Okay im ready whenever!

Answer (score 5):

This is a file that's located on the server's file system. Microsoft definitely doesn't recommend changing this file for the following reasons:

1. Having multiple web front ends means you will have to change the page layout on each of these servers. If the different servers are using different files on their file system, different users will get different results depending on which web front end server they're connecting to.
2. Changes will get overwritten in SharePoint patches

My solution would be to edit the site's masterpage instead. Create a copy of your masterpage called "Seattle_customized" and add the following piece of code anywhere in either body or header tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MakeListEditUrlClickable");

    function MakeListEditUrlClickable()
    {
        if(location.href.indexOf('_layouts/15/listedit.aspx') != -1)
        {
            var ele = jQuery("th:contains('Web Address')").next()
            var text = ele.text().trim();
            ele.html('<a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a>');
        }

    }
<script>
```

Edit: I edited the listedit.aspx page and added the java function. The fix is working! I had no luck when adding to the master page so decided to take this route. I will be looking into why it is not working when added to the master page for future proofing when sharepoint updates are released.

Comment: I wrote it very fast so you might have to tweak it. Also, this will only work if the language of SP is set to English. Otherwise some additional coding is required.

Comment: English is the primary language. I am trying this now, Ill keep posted. Thank you, I appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just click the actual link instead?
[image]

Comment: KISS at it's best

Comment: I do not have that link.......The photo I attached cuts off right before my nav bar.

Comment: then the real question is, why do you not have that link, and how do you get it back.

Comment: Is there a custom masterpage? If that's why the link is not available to you and you don't want to risk breaking this customized masterpage, my solution is still viable.

Comment: I do indeed have a custom masterpage. I have added the solution but got this error, I am trying to insert it in another location in the masterpage file.

Comment: I have it inserted in my masterpage and my library url in document library settings is not a hyperlink yet:(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you weren't able to write javascript. There was a small error (href instead of href() ). I editted my post, please try again with this piece of code.

Comment: I tried with the new code and no luck... I did notice listedit.aspx is stored under C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\listedit.aspx so I tried with that aswell as _layouts/15/listedit.aspx' and neither have helped. I feel I am so close though....

Comment: Try changing it to just listedit.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16406/discussion-between-chromanin-and-nate).

Comment: Im taking off, I will be back tomorrow at 8 am central, lets talk then after I try with the edit

Comment: Would I need to add anything else to the master page? there are call outs at the top for other java functions, would I need one for this script that I am adding?